# How to stop JWplayer embedded in iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, jwplayer

I have an embedded video using JWplayer. Inside the embedded frame, I can easily use the command `jwplayer().stop();` to stop the video.

But I need to stop the video from onclick outside the iframe. How can I do that? I don't have access to jwplayer, so I need a way to call it outside the iframe.

My html:

```
<div class="videoWrapper">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.domain.com/embed/?id=12345" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.close').on('click', function() {
    jwplayer().stop(); // ERROR: jwplayer is undefined
});
```

Comment: That won't work, the code has to be in the actual iframe, not on the parent page.

Comment: To follow up, this might work if both the parent and iframe are on the same domain, but if they are on different domains, the inside iframe will need to allow the parent access. So I doubt this will work.

Comment: why are you using iframe ?

Comment: Most likely embedding the player from another site?

Comment: I'm embedding from another site. I had several embeds in several modal windows, and when closing the modal window, the video was still playing.

I kind of sorted it out with jQuery, by setting the embed src on click closing modal, and the actual source on modal open.

Comment: Yeah, this will not work, since it is across domains.